# Adding my first pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, xcode-workspace

So I used the treehouse tutorial and for the first time, adding a podfile was super easy. That so far has been the easiest part. Now when I try to open my workspace file. I can see the pod and all the different Obj classes. But when I run the project I get 33 brand new errors I have never seen before. I tweet this to someone because they asked if I had errors or warnings but they were indeed errors. They were not present in the actual project but they are in the workspace. Here's the tweet I sent out with the screenshot. I was also adding the JSQMessagesViewController library from GitHub using this in my Podfile

```
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
```

[Missing frameworks and libs](https://twitter.com/KyCo16/status/565550619612966912/photo/1)

[Screenshot from Twitter](http://t.co/VlRCnWxyv0)

**Edit**:
By removing the ParseCrashReporting.framework from the original project it removed 32 errors. The last one is this

```
ld: 91 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
```

Comment: Which pods did you add? Did you try to remove all pods from the Podfile and run `pod update`? Did it work? If so: try to add one pod at a time, perhaps you have a faulty one

Comment: @tilo I typed at the end of this question the only thing in my pod file. I did run pod update. But I guess there is something wrong with the ParseCrashReport and when I remove that framework I am down to one error

Comment: Ok, I thought you added ParseCrashReporting as a pod, too. What does the single error say then?

Comment: Hi Kyle.  Please amend your original question with the entire contents of your Podfile.  Make sure our wrap it in code formatting.

Comment: @tilo I just posted the one error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [issue list of JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/741), this issue (duplicate symbol) occurs when using it in parallel with Parse. Did you remove all frameworks related to Parse (Bolts, ..)?

Comment: Yes I did. I actually just delete the frameworks I had originally in my project and just used the pod versions of them. Everything works now. Thanks!

Comment: there was also multiple folders being searched through in search for frameworks (in the build settings) and it was bringing up the same framework multiple times

Answer (score 0):

The "91 duplicate symbols" error means that you have duplicated your files by adding the Cocoapod without removing the non Cocoapod files.  You need to delete the original JSQMessagesViewController files that you manually downloaded and added to your Xcode project.

Any Libraries / SDKs / Dependencies that you manually dragged and dropped into your main project, need to be deleted from the main project if you are going to add them to your Podfile.  Otherwise you'll get "duplicate" errors.

Also, you may want to add the following to your podfile.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.1'
```